# Asp.net: PageMethods call results in error "Type 'System.String' is not supported for deserialization of an array."

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webmethod, pagemethods

I'm try to use PageMethods to call a code behind static method, but it looks like it never gets to that method. It just fails with the error

```
"Type 'System.String' is not supported for deserialization of an array."
```

I have this working on another part of my program so I'm confused why it's broke here. I'm using a third party plugin jQuery called [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) I wonder if that is the issue? Here is my code:

JavaScript file

```
$('.txtBusinessUnit').chosen().change(function ()
{
    var bu = $('.txtBusinessUnit').val();
    PageMethods.BUChanged(bu, onBUSuccess, onBUFailure); 
});

function onBUSuccess(result) {
alert(result)
}

function onBUFailure(error) {
    alert(error); //errors message listed above
}
```

code behind

```
[WebMethod]
public static string BUChanged(string BU)
{
  return "it works";
}
```

Update: I used the Chrome debugger. It has the following error:

```
POST http://localhost:54234/Default.aspx/BUChanged 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

it errors on ScriptResource.axd with send(body) at this line

```
this._xmlHttpRequest.send(body);
```

With the following error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Service Error)
```

Not sure what this means really..

Comment: What is the value of `var bu` when `change` event happens?

Comment: It's the value of the drop down which is a number. Currently it would be either 1 or 2.

Comment: Not what you think it is, what does the debugger say? I'm guessing it is an array of some sort even if it only contains one item.

Comment: oh wow you're right. I was just doing an alert before to see what value was being passed and assumed it was a number. It was actually an array. I just updated the code with this "var bu = $('.txtBusinessUnit').val()[0];" and it works now. Man I spend so much time on this. Thanks for your help! Lesson learned!